# response.write only working IE for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ashx, response.write

I'm using uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload video to my site then convert them into *.flv using ffmpeg and play preview. But it dosen't fully working with firefox， chrome or safari.

uploadify provides a onComplete interface, so when the script (.ashx, .php) used on your site for saving uploaded files. you can use response.write("blabla") or (echo "blabla") to invoke the javascript function that registed as OnComplete.

i have test with few video files like avi, mpg, mp4, they are less then 50mb,and they all worked with all 4 browsers. However, when i was trying to upload a 75mb mp4 file, it worked in IE, but didn't working in other three. I can see the .flv file has been create in the upload folder, i can see debug messsage output after response.write("blabla"), but the javascript function was not invoked. i.e. the preview didn't play.

anyone knows why?  is there a timeout or something on response.write so after a period of time it wont work? e.g. 75mb file took longer time to convert than other smaller size file i tried.

thansk

Answer (score 0):

Could be a timeout from the server or caching issue. Or an incorrect uploadifiy property as stated [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

after a deeper looking in the source code, and googling around. the problem is narrow down on

DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA and firefox issues

someone reported bug
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1419